# REST api call from Watson Conversation Service

Tags: rest, watson-conversation

I am trying to invoke a sample REST api from [this link here](http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN). I would like to know how to make the REST api call from Watson Conversation Service.
This is how I implemented in the Conversation Service.(Advanced Response)
[image: Advanced Response]

Code here for ease-

```
{
 "context": {
"request": {
  "args": {
    "url_to_invoke": "http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN"
  },
  "name": "http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/iso2code/IN",
  "result": "context.response"
},
"skip_user_input": true
 },
 "output": {}
}
```

As shown in the response,the args and url_to_invoke gives a red underline possibly since its wrong.

How do I take the JSON response and show it to the user?
I tried the following in the following node.

```
<?context.result?>
```

but nothing got printed.

Comment: Conversation does not call the url. You need to do that on your Application layer and then call back to conversation with no input but with context.result set. This will be taken by your next node. You can now give a reply back to user based on the value within context.result

Comment: Look at the Watson SDK's and callbacks. As for displaying the json to an end user, there is the conversation-simple application you can deploy.

Comment: All, I'm facing the same issue, can anyone please point a java client example for the same?